# How do I express this in dot notation

Tags: objective-c

How would I express this line of code in dot notation?

```
[[segue destinationViewController] setDelegate:self];
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue here is that (1) `-[UIStoryboardSegue destinationViewController]` [returns](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIStoryboardSegue_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIStoryboardSegue/destinationViewController) a pointer of type `id` and that (2) dot notation requires a static type.  You will need to cast the returned pointer to the type you want by either explicitly casting

```
((PFXSecondViewController *)segue.destinationViewController).delegate = self;
```

or creating another variable

```
PFXSecondViewController *destinationViewController = segue.destinationViewController;
destinationViewController.delegate = self;
```

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8302674/property-not-found-on-object-of-type-id).

Answer (score 2):

Like so:

```
segue.destinationViewController.delegate = self;
```

Comment: i tried that and for some reason it does not work for me. that's why i asked. i might be doing something differently.

Comment: What version of Xcode? What version of the compiler? Etc, etc. It's all dependent on your environment. This should work, but it depends on your setup.

Comment: Dot notation has been around since at least 2009; the tools are unlikely to be the problem unless you haven't updated your development environment in over 4 years.