# Error: property 'data' not found on object of type 'id'

Tags: ios, properties, object-type

I get this error in the method titleFieldValueChanged which is called when the user changes the value of the text field to update the data model.

In DetailViewController.m:

```
- (IBAction)titleFieldTextChanged:(id)sender
{ 
    self.detailItem.data.title = self.titleField.text;
}
```

I know I have to write this in bracket notation, correct? But I can't figure out how to do that.

Comment: What type of object is detailItem?

Comment: Have you looked at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8302674/property-not-found-on-object-of-type-id

Comment: @Smick yes, but still confused as I am new to objective C

Comment: @Alex detailItem is type ID

Comment: id means "a reference to some random Objective-C object, so i should be like an array or something. Need more info about your self.detailItem.data .... what are these ? You using core data etc... put code on gitHub and ill have a look 4 u

Comment: @Smick if you still have a chance to look at this, it would be greatly appreciated... https://github.com/pjv2/ExerciseNow/tree/master/ExerciseNow errors are in DetailViewController.m lines 96 and 110

Answer (score 0):

The bracket notation would look something like:

```
[[[self detailItem] data] setTitle:[[self titleField] text]];
```

The actual error sounds more like a type error though. Either the detailItem's type doesn't actually have a data property, or it's not obvious what type of class detailItem is.

Comment: With that line of code the error is now: No visible @interface for 'NSData' declares the selector 'setTitle.'

Comment: What type is the detailItem property supposed to be? The error you're getting says that detailItem.data is of type NSData, which is obviously incorrect because NSData doesn't have a title property.

Comment: It is supposed to be type id. If I write that line of code as self.detailItem.data.title = self.titleField.text the error is 'Property 'data' not found on object of type 'id'.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your code, before you segue (i changed it slightly - does same thing) . The code you sent crashes, when trying to segue from master to detail. These are the bigger issues I found.

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"showDetail"]) {
        DetailViewController *dvc = segue.destinationViewController;
        NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];
        NSDate *object = _exercises[indexPath.row];
        dvc.detailItem = object;
    }
}

// in detail view
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSDate *detailItem;
```

Your "object" that you are passing to the detail view controller is a NSDate object.

You cannot set a title to a NSDate object.

You also have a problem when you do

```
[[self detailItem] setFullImage:fullImage];
[[self detailItem] setThumbImage:thumbImage];
```

Again your trying to set an image to your NSDate object.

I suggest you follow along with this tutorial, it will show a good example of what you are trying to make, as you mentioned you are a beginner.

[iOS Tutorial: How To Create A Simple iPhone App](http://www.raywenderlich.com/1797/ios-tutorial-how-to-create-a-simple-iphone-app-part-1)