# iOS - Property 'name' not found on object of type 'NSArray'

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, ios7

My question is similar to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19060609/error-property-data-not-found-on-object-of-type-id) but I feel different enough to warrant me asking here.

I'm creating my first iOS app, a basic master-detail app and using JSONModel to pull in an API although I don't think that much is relevant in this case. I have a UITableView in which each row represents a boxer, each boxer has a name, weight class, record etc, this all works well. Where I'm having problems is displaying that data on the individual detail pages. Mainly I cannot work out how I should be passing the data in the segue, I know that I want to use the row to pass the associated boxer object, but cannot seem to figure out the correct method. In my code below I've got NSArray but have also tried NSMutableArray and NSObject, each with the same error: Property 'name' not found on object of type 'NSWhatever'. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

BoxerMasterViewController.m

```
-(UITableViewCell*)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
 Boxer* boxerDetails = _feed.boxers[indexPath.row];

 BoxerTableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"BoxerCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
 cell.boxerNameLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", boxerDetails.name];
}


- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
 if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"showBoxerDetail"]) {
    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];
    NSArray *object = _feed.boxers[indexPath.row];
    [[segue destinationViewController] setBoxerDetailItem:object];

 }
}
```

BoxerDetailViewController.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
@interface BoxerDetailViewController : UIViewController
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSArray *boxerDetailItem;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *boxerName;
@end
```

BoxerDetailViewController.m

```
self.boxerName.text = [self.boxerDetailItem.name];
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You use `boxerDetails.name` on an object of type `Boxer`.  Is that the type that you want `boxerDetailItem` to be?

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) Boxer *boxerDetailItem;
```

You use this line of code differently in the two situations:

```
Boxer* boxerDetails = _feed.boxers[indexPath.row];

NSArray *object = _feed.boxers[indexPath.row];
```

The object is either a Boxer or an NSArray.  You decide which.  (My guess is Boxer)

This is my interpretation of your code:

```
-(UITableViewCell*)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
 Boxer* boxerDetails = _feed.boxers[indexPath.row];

 BoxerTableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"BoxerCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
 cell.boxerNameLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", boxerDetails.name];
}


- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
 if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"showBoxerDetail"]) {
    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];
    Boxer *object = _feed.boxers[indexPath.row];
    [[segue destinationViewController] setBoxerDetailItem:object];

 }
} 

@interface BoxerDetailViewController : UIViewController
@property (strong, nonatomic) Boxer *boxerDetailItem;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *boxerName;
@end
```

Comment: eugh, you are correct, that'll teach me for running through a hundred tutorials and seemingly taking bits of code from each. I'm going to fix what I've got, and if no errors mark this as the correct response. Thanks!

Comment: That is in a portion of code that you do not have listed, so I have no suggestions for you there.

Answer (score 1):

You want "boxerDetailItem" to be of type "Boxer", since you are passing in a single "Boxer" object not an "NSArray" of "Boxer" objects.